# HTML WYSIWYG editor component that supports spell checking

Tags: c#, .net, html, wysiwyg

Looking for an **HTML** WYSIWYG editor for C#/.NET that supports taking in HTML as a source, solid editing functionality + **spell checking** and then exporting it as a valid HTML document.

Comment: Something like `contentEditable`?

Comment: Have you looked at TinyMCE? http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/  (not sure about .net spell check though)

Comment: Thanks guys for all the tips, at the moment Netrixcomponent looks the most promising. TinyMCE and CKEditor I also had a look but we decided not to mix technologies in our C# client so they are out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Try www.Netrixcomponent.net – hungryMind Jan 20 at 19:34"

This was exactly what we are looking for, thx !

Answer (score 0):

Refer to Mozilla Kompozer. It has spell-checking and a decent GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo). There's also an [asp.net control](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=15882) available